# How do splitting rounds work?

Tags: depth

After buying splitting rounds, I'd expect to see three projectiles from my gun and three bullet holes in the wall... but I still see just one.

1. Do the rounds split after they're shot?  If so, how far away from the shark do I need to be to ensure my bullets are splitting?
2. Do they split horizontally?  Vertically?  Randomly?  Is one of the three always traveling exactly where I'm aiming?  How much do they spread?
3. I heard each round does only 70% damage.  Does that mean each one of the three does 70% damage, or 70/3 = 23% damage?  If I hit the shark with all three parts of a split bullet, how much damage will it take?